# Why does Folium Render colours in a single colour?

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

Caveat - I am new to Folium so any assistance will be appreciated... I am trying to create a choropleth for South America with the population density on the countries. I have the following data:

```
idx id  pop_den location
0   AR  16.177  Argentina
1   BO  10.202  Bolivia
2   BR  25.040  Brazil
3   CL  24.282  Chile
4   CO  44.223  Colombia
5   EC  66.939  Ecuador
6   GY  3.952   Guyana
7   PY  17.144  Paraguay
8   PE  25.129  Peru
9   SR  3.612   Suriname
10  UY  19.751  Uruguay
11  VE  36.253  Venezuela
```

This is the code to read in the geo.json file

```
sa_geojson = geopandas.read_file('continent_South_America_subunits.json')
```

An example of the file is below:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature","id":"AR", "properties": { "scalerank": 0, "featurecla": "Admin-0 map subunit", "labelrank": 2.000000, "sovereignt": "Argentina", "sov_a3": "ARG", "adm0_dif": 0.000000, "level": 2.000000, "type": "Sovereign country", "admin": "Argentina", "adm0_a3": "ARG", "geou_dif": 0.000000, "geounit": "Argentina", "gu_a3": "ARG", "su_dif": 0.000000, "subunit": "Argentina", "su_a3": "ARG", "brk_diff": 0.000000, "name": "Argentina", "name_long": "Argentina", "brk_a3": "ARG", "brk_name": "Argentina", "brk_group": "", "abbrev": "Arg.", "postal": "AR", "formal_en": "Argentine Republic", "formal_fr": "", "note_adm0": "", "note_brk": "", "name_sort": "Argentina", "name_alt": "", "mapcolor7": 3.000000, "mapcolor8": 1.000000, "mapcolor9": 3.000000, "mapcolor13": 13.000000, "pop_est": 40913584.000000, "gdp_md_est": 573900.000000, "pop_year": -99.000000, "lastcensus": 2010.000000, "gdp_year": -99.000000, "economy": "5. Emerging region: G20", "income_grp": "3. Upper middle income", "wikipedia": -99.000000, "fips_10": "", "iso_a2": "AR", "iso_a3": "ARG", "iso_n3": "032", "un_a3": "032", "wb_a2": "AR", "wb_a3": "ARG", "woe_id": -99.000000, "adm0_a3_is": "ARG", "adm0_a3_us": "ARG", "adm0_a3_un": -99.000000, "adm0_a3_wb": -99.000000, "continent": "South America", "region_un": "Americas", "subregion": "South America", "region_wb": "Latin America & Caribbean", "name_len": 9.000000, "long_len": 9.000000, "abbrev_len": 4.000000, "tiny": -99.000000, "homepart": 1.000000 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -68.654124, -54.886244 ], [ -68.654135, -54.886245 ], [ -68.654135, -54.886244 ], [ -68.642343, -54.853653 ], [ -68.641988, -54.799174 ],
```

This is the code to build the map and overlay the Choropleth

```
## Build the Map for South America

map = flm.Map(location = [-22.5,-56.5], zoom_start = 2.5)

flm.Choropleth (
    geo_data = sa_geojson,
    name = "choropleth",
    date = cvd_tot_sa1,
    columns = ["id", "population_density"],
    key_on = "feature.id",
    fill_color = "YlGn",
    fill_opacity = 0.7,
    legend_name = "population density",
).add_to(map)

flm.LayerControl().add_to(map)
map
```

The output it is giving me is
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIOtY.png)

I have read the posts and ensured that the `id` is the same in both the json and the data file and checked the lat and long in the json file are correct to ensure it is mapped in the right location.

Any advice would be helpful - thx in advance

- Python - 3.7.9
- Folium -  0.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is simply a typo. The specified parameter name for data is 'data'. The first time you start a library, there is a lot to learn about the data structure and how to tie it to the data. You may have spent a lot of time solving the problem, but it will definitely come back to you in the form of great results in the future. Good luck!

```
map = flm.Map(location = [-22.5,-56.5], zoom_start = 2.5)

flm.Choropleth (
    geo_data = sa_geojson,
    name = "choropleth",
    data = cvd_tot_sa1, # date->data
    columns = ["id", "population_density"],
    key_on = "feature.id",
    fill_color = "YlGn",
    fill_opacity = 0.7,
    legend_name = "population density",
).add_to(map)

flm.LayerControl().add_to(map)
map
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, you've certainly picked up an issue I was having (accurate code/ typing..). I now get the legend bar and its much closer but the overall graphic is still rendering in an opaque black - a single colour for all of South America. I can toggle the layer on and off so it appears to be an issue with the layer and only the layer - still stumped.

Comment: If you have a geojson file, you might be able to clarify the issue more concretely.